# Extracting bounding box as .jpg

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, object-detection-api

Extract the detected object along with the bounding box and save it as an image on my disk.

I have taken the code of Edge Electronics and successfully trained and tested the model. I got the bounding box on my images.

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import sys
from glob import glob
import glob
import csv
from PIL import Image
import json

sys.path.append("..")

# Import utilites
from utils import label_map_util
from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util

MODEL_NAME = 'inference_graph'

CWD_PATH = os.getcwd()

PATH_TO_CKPT = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,MODEL_NAME,'frozen_inference_graph.pb')

PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,'training','labelmap.pbtxt')

PATH_TO_IMAGE = list(glob.glob("C:\\new_multi_cat\\models\\research\\object_detection\\img_test\\*jpeg"))

NUM_CLASSES = 3

label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)

detection_graph = tf.Graph()

with detection_graph.as_default():
    od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
        serialized_graph = fid.read()
        od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
        tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

    sess = tf.Session(graph=detection_graph)

image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')


detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
detection_classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')

num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')


for paths in range(len(PATH_TO_IMAGE)):
    image = cv2.imread(PATH_TO_IMAGE[paths])
    image_expanded = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

    (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run([detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],feed_dict={image_tensor: image_expanded})


    vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
    image,
    np.squeeze(boxes),
    np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
    np.squeeze(scores),
    category_index,
    use_normalized_coordinates=True,
    line_thickness=4,
    min_score_thresh=0.80)


    white_bg_img = 255*np.ones(PATH_TO_IMAGE[paths].shape, np.uint8)
    vis_util.draw_bounding_boxes_on_image(
    white_bg_img ,
    np.squeeze(boxes),
    color='red',
    thickness=4)
    cv2.imwrite("bounding_boxes.jpg", white_bg_img)

    boxes = np.squeeze(boxes)
    for i in range(len(boxes)):
        box[0]=box[0]*height
        box[1]=box[1]*width
        box[2]=box[2]*height
        box[3]=box[3]*width
    roi = image[box[0]:box[2],box[1]:box[3]].copy()
    cv2.imwrite("box_{}.jpg".format(str(i)), roi)
```

This is the error I am getting:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "objd_1.py", line
75, in <module>
     white_bg_img = 255*np.ones(PATH_TO_IMAGE[paths].shape, np.uint8) AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

I have searched a lot but not able to identify what is wrong in my code. Why am I not able to extract the detected region as an image?

Comment: @halfer I am new here. Apologies for my post. Will keep your suggested points in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to take `shape` from a file name instead of the image. Replace

```
white_bg_img = 255*np.ones(PATH_TO_IMAGE[paths].shape, np.uint8)
```

to

```
white_bg_img = 255*np.ones(image.shape, np.uint8)
```

**Edit:** corrected code

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import sys
from glob import glob
import glob
import csv
from PIL import Image
import json

sys.path.append("..")

# Import utilites
from utils import label_map_util
from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util

MODEL_NAME = 'inference_graph'

CWD_PATH = os.getcwd()

PATH_TO_CKPT = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,MODEL_NAME,'frozen_inference_graph.pb')

PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,'training','labelmap.pbtxt')

PATH_TO_IMAGE = list(glob.glob("C:\\new_multi_cat\\models\\research\\object_detection\\img_test\\*jpeg"))

NUM_CLASSES = 3

label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)

detection_graph = tf.Graph()

with detection_graph.as_default():
    od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
        serialized_graph = fid.read()
        od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
        tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

    sess = tf.Session(graph=detection_graph)

image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')


detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
detection_classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')

num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')


for paths in range(len(PATH_TO_IMAGE)):
    image = cv2.imread(PATH_TO_IMAGE[paths])
    image_expanded = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

    (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run([detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],feed_dict={image_tensor: image_expanded})


    vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
    image,
    np.squeeze(boxes),
    np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
    np.squeeze(scores),
    category_index,
    use_normalized_coordinates=True,
    line_thickness=4,
    min_score_thresh=0.80)


    white_bg_img = 255*np.ones(image.shape, np.uint8)
    vis_util.draw_bounding_boxes_on_image_array(
    white_bg_img ,
    np.squeeze(boxes),
    color='red',
    thickness=4)
    cv2.imwrite("bounding_boxes.jpg", white_bg_img)

    boxes = np.squeeze(boxes)
    for i in range(len(boxes)):
        box[0]=box[0]*height
        box[1]=box[1]*width
        box[2]=box[2]*height
        box[3]=box[3]*width
    roi = image[box[0]:box[2],box[1]:box[3]].copy()
    cv2.imwrite("box_{}.jpg".format(str(i)), roi)
```

Comment: I did as you suggested but this gives up another error. AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'load' because the value in variable image is a numpy ndarray. I am looping through a directory of images and reading it in image variable like this for paths in range(len(PATH_TO_IMAGE)):
    image = cv2.imread(PATH_TO_IMAGE[paths])

Comment: @Ankit `pilImage = Image.fromarray(image)` to get PIL Image from numpy array. Then pass this `pilImage` to PIL functions instead (or other functions that expect PIL Images) of passing numpy arrays. `visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array` expects PIL image for example.

Comment: Your problem was clearly stated as specific error message. If proposed solution solves this problem, please consider accepting the answer. If you have any other problem, please ask another question

Comment: @Oliort: changed for paths in range(len(PATH_TO_IMAGE)):
    image = cv2.imread(PATH_TO_IMAGE[paths])
    pilImage = Image.fromarray(image) and passed pilImage to visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array. Got the error     np.copyto(image, np.array(image_pil))
TypeError: copyto() argument 1 must be numpy.ndarray, not Image

Comment: @Sharky If any solution solves my problem I will definitely accept it as the answer

Comment: @Ankit that's because you now pass your PIL image in all places where it is needed and where it is not (where actually numpy array is needed). Sharky is right, there might be more problems with your code, but it should be a separate question, as these problems do not have anything in common.

Comment: @Oliort I made changes to 2 places only 1) for paths in range(len(PATH_TO_IMAGE)):
    image = cv2.imread(PATH_TO_IMAGE[paths])
    pilImage = Image.fromarray(image) and 2) visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
    pilImage). What else can I do to get it working? Also can I have your email id. We could get in touch over there for a while so that I can share you my code file if u don't mind plz

Comment: @Oliort may be you can figure out the error much quicker and save time for both of us if I share you the code file

Comment: @Ankit sorry I made a mistake, correct it back `visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array`. Still there is something else that awaits for PIL instead of numpy as you get the AttributeError, or maybe some other issues. Sorry but I'm not going to fix everything in your program for you. You should do some effort yourself.

Comment: @Oliort So pilImage should not be used anywhere? I am just asking you to have a look at my code. I'll make the changes on my own

Comment: @Ankit Ok, found it. Its `draw_bounding_boxes_on_image` (not `visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array`), that expects PIL. But you can use `draw_bounding_boxes_on_image_array` and then you **maybe** won't need PIL.

Comment: @Oliort passed pilImage to draw_bounding_boxes_on_image. This is the error   File "objd_1.py", line 75, in <module>
    white_bg_img = 255*np.ones(pilImage.shape, np.uint8)
AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: @Ankit posted corrected code in the edit. Should do future work yourself.

Comment: @Oliort Thanks for your help man. I read the wrong function in your edit(my bad). Made the changes you suggested. Still facing issues with box variable but will try to solve it soon. As of now it says box variable is not defined

Comment: @Ankit accept an answer please if it was helpfull and fixed the problem you decsribed in the question. I would appreciate it.

Comment: @Oliort I have clicked the UP Arrow twice but as my reputation is low its not getting displayed here. But I really appreciate your efforts.

Comment: @Ankit You should use accept button (check mark), not an upvote button (up arrow) to accept answers. It is under vote buttons.

Comment: @Oliort Done brother. Once again thanks a lot for your precious time and efforts